# How to generate two sequences of random numbers that follow a similar (but not equal) sinusoidal form?

Tags: r

I want to create a simulated plot in which I represent two devices which are measuring temperature in the water at different depths over time. Let's say `dev.1` (recording water temperature at 10 meters depth) and `dev.2` (recording water temperature at 30 meters depth). Since it is a simulation (my goal is to illustrate something it does not matter here), I would like to generate a dataframe which allows me to make a plot like this one:

[image]

As you can see in the draft, I would like to create two variables (`dev.1` and `dev.2`) for which the temperature (in the plot would be `value`) oscillates over time in a sinusoidal way. As you can see, in both devices the temperature change similarly but not equally (this is important).

Does anyone know how could I create this dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you like this?

```
t <- seq(0, 3*pi, .1)
red <- sin(.95*t+.3) + jitter(.1*t, amount = .03) + 5
blue <- sin(t + rnorm(length(t), .4, .03)) + .3*t + 2

plot(red, col = "red", ylim = c(0,7), type="l")
lines(blue, col = "blue")
```

You can adjust wiggle, phase etc by the different constants.

**Edit to answer questions in the first comment**

> I would like to create a specific number of values (n=1000)

I assume that's values on the time axis. In my code

```
t <- seq(0, 3*pi, .1)
```

t values (those on the x axis) range from `0` to `3*pi` in steps of `.1`. 1000 steps in the same range can be computed via

```
t <- seq(0, 3*pi, length.out = 1000)
```

> I would like to force both lines to be a little bit more different between them.

That is very unspecific. If you want the phases to differ more, change the `red` line's `.95` to something smaller like `.8` and `.3` tp `.9` as in `sin(.8*t+.9)` and see if that is radical enough change or not and then play with the numbers according to taste. If you want the lines closer together or further apart, just change the `+ 5` in the `red` definition or the `+ 2` in the blue definition.

For aesthetic reasons, I often prefer `ggplot2` graphs to base graphs. YMMV but you should check both options before deciding which one to use:

```
library(ggplot2)
t <- seq(0, 4*pi, length.out = 1000)
red <- sin(.8*t+1.5) + jitter(.1*t, amount = .03) + sin(.1*t) + 5
blue <- sin(t + rnorm(length(t), .4, .03)) + .5*cos(.5*t) + 4
waves <- data.frame(time = rep(1:1000,2),
                    temp = c(red, blue),
                    depth = gl(2, 1000, labels = c("shallow", "deep")))
ggplot(waves, aes(x = time, y = temp, color = depth)) +
  geom_line() +
  theme_bw() + xlab("Time") + ylab("Temperature")
```

Comment: thanks. It is perfect. Could you explain the main parameters? I would like to play with that a little bit and if I know what the different numbers do it will be easier. For example, I would like to create a specific number of values (`n`=1000) and I would like to force both lines to be a little bit more different between them.

Comment: I have edited my answer and added some more information. In the end there is no way around but just trying things out until the graphics represents what you want it to say.

Answer (score 2):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)
t=seq(0,10,0.1)

noise_level = 0.25

dev.1 = sin(t) + 20 + runif(length(t), -noise_level, noise_level)
dev.2 = sin(t) + 25 + runif(length(t), -noise_level, noise_level)

df <- data.frame(t=t, dev.1 = dev.1, dev.2 = dev.2)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(dev.1, dev.2)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = t, y = value, color = name)) +
  geom_line()
```

You can change the noise level to achieve more or less noise around the sinusoidal wave.

Comment: I think the intent of the OP's drawing *may* have been to show that the phase (as well as the overall height) of the two traces varies?

Comment: Maybe ... it wasn't quite clear to me from the drawing and the description, I guess @Dekike can clarify?

Comment: Thanks @BenBolker and Valeri Voev for your time. In fact, you both are right. I would like to get noise in the phase (like Bernhard got in other answer), however, the noise you created is also nice for my purpose. So, in addition to what you did, if you Valeri Voev know how to get change a little bit the phase among variables would be perfect.

Comment: In this answer you can see `sin(t)` twice. changing the phase can easily be achieved by changing one of these to `sin(t+c)` with `c` being a constant, e.g. `sin(t+pi/2)`. The larger `c` the larger the phase shift.